# Are there any asynchronous non-network I/O frameworks for Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous

Many times, asynchronous I/O is synonymous with networked or file-based I/O (e.g. Twisted, Eventlet, asyncore ...).

However, I am currently in the midst of writing a Python toolkit to control motors. This should be asynchronous most of the time, so that several motors can be controlled at once. Right now, everything is based on threads but the underlying problem is so fundamental that I thought, that there must be an asynchronous framework that helps with this. Do you know of any?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in a "framework"?  A simple `select.epoll` main loop would work for a number of situations, assuming that you're talking to the motors via a file-descriptor-like object.  Any of the asynchronous frameworks that support this sort of mechanism (e.g., `gevent`) would also work out just fine.

Comment: There are different means to talk to the motors. Sometimes it's via a CORBA interface, sometimes via TCP/IP, sometimes just a serial interface. What I'm looking for, is a system that abstracts these kind of things for me in a platform-independent way.

Answer (score 0):

No need for 3rd-party frameworks.  Use [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html), which is in the standard library.